# Why ReplaySubject is getting called on ngOnInit?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular9

I am trying to interact between 2 components i.e. the header component and the router-outlet component which contains a reactive form. Some days ago after great research, I got an answer which told me to use shared service and there takes a `ReplaySubject` variable. This will act as an `Observable` which will be called in `ngOnInit` of the component in `router-outlet`. So the problem arises here. Everything is working fine but just now while testing noticed a small bug. After clicking the button in header the event is firing in the main component but it is staying active until I hard reload the page.
Below is my code:

**shared.service.ts**

```
public updateSrc = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
public updateClick = this.updateSrc.asObservable();
```

**header.component.ts** (A button is clicked here)

```
update() {
  return this.dataService.updateSrc.next(true);
}
```

**main.component.ts** (Here the main operation is happening on click of header button)

```
updateClicked = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.updateClick.pipe(takeUntil(this.updateClicked)).subscribe({
    next: value => console.log(value); // At first click of button this happening perfectly but if coming from different route & had clicked the header button previously this thing is getting triggered
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.updateClicked.next(); // Closing subscription here
}
```

Can anyone suggest to me how to reset this?

Comment: The ReplaySubject stores the “current” value. This means it send “old” values to new subscribers.

Comment: any way to destroy it? I am closing the subscription still its same

Comment: Pretty sure you have to call `complete()` on the `updateClicked` Subject additionally to `next()` to trigger `takeUntil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ReplaySubject` (and the `BehaviorSubject`) stores previously emitted values and emit those whenever a new subscriber is added.

If you don't want new subscribers to receive previously emitted value(s), you can always use `Subject` which doesn't store emitted values.

You may want to read more about the available variations in [the docs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject).

Comment: yes I tried this after that and thanks for the difference